# Prove function is not onto

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ be given by $$f(x)=\frac{x + a}{x + b}.$$
The constants $a$ and $b$ must be evaluated to the following:

- $a$ is the sum of the first 4 digits of your student number
- $b$ is the product of the last two non-zero digits of your student number.

Examples:

- If your student number is $30247340$, then $a = 9$ and $b = 12$.
- If your student number is $1002110833567$, then $a = 3$ and $b = 42$.

Determine if $f$ is a bijection. If it is a bijection, find its inverse.

I used contradiction to show that $f$ is one to one, but I have no idea how to prove it is not onto. Since I don't know the exact values of $a$ and $b$, I am unable to find a counter-example to show that it is not onto. What other approaches can I use?

Comment: For what value of $x$ is $f(x) = 1$?

Comment: If $a=b$, then $f$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: Let's hope your student number is not $5034000$

Comment: "If your student number is 30247340, then a=9 and b=12
.
If your student number is 1002110833567
, then a=3 and b=42."  Then $a$ and $b$ aren't constant, are if they different from student to student.  Is $f$ a *different* function for different students.  As Henry points out if you number is such that $a = b$ then the function is the constant function $f(x) =1$.

Comment: But in general the way to show if something is surgective is to set $f(x) = m$ for any $m\in \mathbb R^+$ and solve for $x$.  If $x$ is well defined for all possible $m$ it is surjective.  $f(x)=\frac {x+a}{x+b}= m\implies x+a=m(x+b)\implies mx-x = a-mb\implies x(m-1)=a-mb$.  If $m\ne 1$ we have $x =\frac{a-mb}{m-1}$ will be so that $f(x) =m$.  But if $m = 1$ we are skewered six ways to sunday.  $f(x)=1$ is impossible to solve if $a\ne b$. And if $a=b$ then $(x)=\frac{x+a}{x+b} =1$ and $f(x) \ne 1$ is impossible to solve.  Either way, it's not surjective. (And it's not injective if $a=b$).